# Parsing just the content in HTML nodes via Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

Suppose I have parsed a line of HTML that is the following...

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="blah"><img src="logo.png" border="0"></img><br><span class="red">Go to google!</span></a>
```

This is just an example...but how would I go about stripping everything EXCEPT the following:

```
http://www.google.com
logo.png
Go to google!
```

Also, is it possible to search for wildcards?

Answer (score 1):

If you could make use of some gems it will be a very simple job. I would recommend you `Mechanize gem`. Reference: http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML '<a href="http://www.google.com" class="blah"><img src="logo.png" border="0"></img><br><span class="red">Go to google!</span></a>'
doc.xpath('//*/@href|//*/@src|//*/text()').map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by wildcards